# reload layout in Masonry

Tags: jquery, requirejs, jquery-masonry

I am using the masonry control with require.js and I have situation where I need reload the masonary controls.

I was looking at [this entry,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942897/height-of-hidden-div-doesnt-expand-with-masonry-content) but I keep on getting object not found exception.

Here is my code to load the masonary:

```
masnorySet = function () {
            var container = document.querySelector('.pinStyle');
            var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
                columnWidth: 1,
                itemSelector: '.item'
            });
            msnry.layout();
        },
reloadMasnory = function () {
            //var container = document.querySelector('.pinStyle');
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942897/height-of-hidden-div-doesnt-expand-with-masonry-content
        },
```

This is how I load it as module:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "masonry": "../../../../lib/masonry.pkgd",

   }
});
```

**THE QUESTION IS: how do I call the reload method given the way I am using masonary control?**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jmogera/6tm4d/ Here is the example of div getting display: none. I want masorny control to reset basically after that happens